# how make my hook valid ? Object are not valid as a react child

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i'm doing my hook with firestore. I did praticly exactly the same on an ohter page and he works. But this one i have the error :  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

On my  console i can see an empty array like that

```
cc []
```

also my hook

```
async function GetFriendsRequest() {
  const [TeamsArray, updateTeamArray] = React.useState([]);

  firestore()
    .collection("Teams")
    // Filter results
    .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log("no documents found");
      } else {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          let Teams = doc._data;
          TeamsArray.length = 0;
          updateTeamArray((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);

          console.log("cc", JSON.stringify(TeamsArray));
        });
      }
    });
  return (
    <View>
      {TeamsArray.map((element, key) => {
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>
              {element.MembersList.nickName}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.Activity} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Something is wrong ?

Comment: {_U, _V, _W, _X} looks like a promise. Is it supposed to be doc.data()? Also, updateTeamArray is asynchronous so your console log won't show what you expect.

Comment: Yes is suppose to be doc.data(), what do you mean ? On the other one everything work well, i tried to take of the asynchronous but still doesn't work :(

Comment: In the other example you mention, you are consulting the same collectoin from firestore and it have data? what is the difference between the 2 code snippets you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.map()` callback isn't returning anything. You need to replace the braces with parentheses in the body of the callback in order to return your JSX:

```
{TeamsArray.map((element, key) => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>
              {element.MembersList.nickName}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.Activity} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>;
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mistakes in your component, you'll have to fix those first before debugging.

```
// This is a component, not a hook, so use it like <GetFriendsRequest />
async function GetFriendsRequest() {
  const [TeamsArray, updateTeamArray] = React.useState([]);

  // This code was in the render loop
  // put it inside a function so it doesn't run on every single render
  const init = async () => {
    const uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID");

    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      // Filter results
      .where("uid", "==", uid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          const results = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
            let Teams = doc.data();
            // Don't mutate react state, it should be treated as immutable
            // TeamsArray.length = 0;

            // This is an async function, but it's being
            // called as if it were syncronous
            // updateTeamArray((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);
            results.push(Teams);
          });

          // Schedule a single state update
          updateTeamArray([...results, ...TeamsArray]);
        }
      });
  }

  // Use an expression like this to debug
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log state every time it updates
    console.log(TeamsArray);
  }, [TeamsArray]);

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {TeamsArray.map((element, key) => {
        // Something has to be returned from this map
        return <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>
              {element.MembersList.nickName}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.Activity} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tryed, same, error as before and no console.log inside the bundler :(